# In the execution of a program, are events like threads? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, events

I have a background worker thread continuously updating the data displayed in a window from a network source. I also have a button which will fire an event.

My question is, at what stage (relative to the background worker execution) is the event method executed? Is it similar to threads in that they happen simultaneously? I.e, will the background worker will still be running whilst my button click method is executing? In which case, I will need to use locking. Or will the background worker pause until the button click method has terminated?

Comment: The event _handler_ is executed on the same thread as whatever triggers is, unless there is custom code to fire the handler on a _different_ thread. So if the background worker calls a click event handler, it will pause until the click event handler(s) have terminated.  If the handler is executed because a button was clicked, it will execute in the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events raised by UI controls (e.g. buttons) execute in the main thread, a.k.a. the UI thread. Events you raise yourself are raised on whatever thread you raise them on. All event raisings block the execution of their own thread until they complete. They're not very special, when you call them: Just a little syntactic sugar around calling an arbitrary list of delegates.

In the absence of any [explicit synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964(v=vs.110).aspx) code, any other threads humming along the background will merrily continue to execute.

If you need or want to communicate between an event handler in the UI thread and a worker thread, you'll need to write explicit code to do so. Nothing special here: Just two threads.

And if you've got both an event handler and a thread putting their greasy little mitts on the same object, and if the operations on that object are not atomic, you're correct: You'll need locking. [Thread-safe collections may come in handy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx).